# Handling interface rotation in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, autoresizingmask

Very simple question, but I'm asking as there seems to be a lot of conflicting views and I've been completely unable to find a definitive answer, let alone a modern one.

I use Auto Layout for 99% of my handling of the user changing from portrait to landscape or vice-versa in a `UIViewController`. Works great. But sometimes, I have to rely on frames still for one reason or another.

How would I best handle this?

You have `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`, `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, the `NSNotification` methods with checking status bar, and I'm sure there's some others.

If I want to change the position of a view when the user rotates, *which method should I be changing the frame in*? And is it best to do it with a simple `setFrame:` or should I be using autoresizing masks?

Comment: Definitely setFrame: if you know where the view should be. I usually calculate from the size of the self.view and then setFrame:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since iOS6, you should not be using `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`. These are only called on the front-most presented view controller, and will not be called on others. This means if you have a pushed view controller or a presented view controller, all others will not layout correctly.

Instead, you should always use `viewWillLayout` and `viewDidLayout` to handle rotation. They are both called inside an animation block, so anything you do which is animatable, will be animated.

For positioning views, you can either set the frames yourself, or use auto-layout constraints and adjust the constraints in `viewDidLayout`. If you go the auto-layout route, never remove and add constraints. Use the same constraints as much as possible and just adjust their `constant` values.

Comment: Why adjust the constraints in `didLayout` versus `willLayout`? And I assume you're referring to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: @DougSmith Because it is likely you want to setup your constraints after other views have been layout already. With auto-layout it matters less where you do the layout, as both would achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Okay. And if you were referring to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, doesn't it get called in numerous cases, not only on rotation? How do I know only to change things on rotation, and figure out what rotation will be rotated to? It'd be great if you could post a short code example of how it would be used on rotation.

Comment: @DougSmith Why would you worry about that? When layout is called by the system, you need to make sure the system is layout correctly. If your constraints do not change, nothing will happen.

Comment: How do I find out what the orientation is when it gets called though?

Comment: @DougSmith `[UIApplication sharedApplicaiton].statusBarOrientation`

Comment: Depending upon the constraints, you could get a crash if using this method. The constraints are evaluated before `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called. If they are absurd in the new orientation, a crash will result. The method `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, on the other hand, is called before the constraints are evaluated, so absurd constraints can be removed or amended before a crash would result.

Answer (score -1):

When I'm changing the main view frame, I typically adjust the frame in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` if I need to.  Then I adjust any subviews by overriding layoutSubviews for my main view.

I don't know that this is a definitive answer, though -  I don't think there really is a definitive answer - it depends on how your application is structured.

`wilLRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` are best used for stuff you need to do before and after rotation, respectively (for example, disabling user interaction before the rotation begins, and reenabling it after).  Everything else should be done in layoutSubviews if possible.

Autoresizing masks are useful sometimes, but I usually lay everything out manually to avoid any surprises when things change between iOS releases (as they often do).

Comment: These two methods should not be used for view layout. See my answer on why not.